# Shortening an almost-repeating code in python3

Tags: python-3.x, repeat

I have a code in python 3 that "almost repeats" itself and I'm looking for an easy way to shorten it.

What I have is a function f(x1, ..., xN) with N variables. The user selects a variable, say x5, and gets a plot of f vs x5 with other variables fixed. I can always write by hand N functions, each doing the following for a different xi:

```
def get_Array_To_Plot_x5(x1, ..., x5Start, x5End, numberOfX5, ..., xN):
      return [f(x1, ..., xN) for x5 in numpy.linspace(xiStart, xiEnd, numberOfXi)]
```

Then I'd call the proper get_Array_To_Plot_xi function (get_Array_To_Plot_x5 in this example) in my main script depending on user input, and plot this array.

Is there a better way of writing this code? I can write another code that writes this script as a text file for me, but I'm hoping for a more elegant solution if possible.

Edit: Adding sample code as requested by Mad Physicist:

Here's the code I've written (I'm calculating energy levels of an s-wave topological superconductor using the Kwant library):

```
def get SWaveEnergies(V0, mu, B_Zeeman, alpha, Delta, W, L, noOfLevels, a, t):
   return some_floating_number

def SWave_vsMu(muStart, muEnd, noOfmu, V0, B_Zeeman, alpha, Delta, W, L, noOfLevels=6, a=1, t=1.0):
    return [SWaveEnergies(V0, mu, B_Zeeman, alpha, Delta, W, L, noOfLevels, a, t) for mu in np.linspace(muStart, muEnd, noOfmu)]
```

I've written this with different `xiStart`, `xiEnd`, `noOfxi`. User's command line input will determine the function I call.

Comment: Are `x1...xN` provided as a single array or as separate variables?

Comment: Reading this over, it would be very helpful if you provided a bit more context, at least in terms of how the arguments are to be set up and how your function would be called.

Comment: Originally, the user gives single values for all xi, except for the one they choose. For the chosen value, they effectively give an array (or enough info to construct an array.)

Comment: So you could technically put the variables into an array? Either way, please show a bit more code, it will help me help you find a solution.

Comment: Yes, I could, but the elements of the array will be all floating numbers except one, which needs to be an array itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable in a `for` loop or list comprehension can actually be any expression you can assign to (a "lvalue"), not just a simple variable name.  This means that if you have all of your parameters in a list, you can iterate an arbitrary element of that list via indexing, without duplicating any code.  Something like this:

```
def get_Array_To_Plot(whichParam, start, end, number, *args):
    args = list(args)   # must be writable list, not tuple
    values = numpy.linspace(start, end, number)
    return [f(*args) for args[whichParam] in values]
```

You would need to provide a dummy value in the parameter list for the parameter you will be looping over.

Comment: Have you tested this comprehension: `[f(*args) for args[whichParam] in values]`?

Comment: This is awesome: I did not know you could stash the loop variable into an arbitrary location like a list element like that. Thanks for teaching me a new thing that is very useful!